# select 2 table in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

`@Entity
public class Movie {

```
private Long id;
private String title;
private String summary;
private long duration;
private LocalDateTime startDate;
private LocalDateTime endDate;
private Set<Session> sessions = new HashSet<>();


public Movie() {
}


public Movie(Long id, String title, String summary, long duration, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.summary = summary;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
}


public Movie(String title, String summary, long duration, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.summary = summary;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="movie")
public Set<Session> getSessions() {
    return sessions;
}


public void setSessions(Set<Session> sessions) {
    this.sessions = sessions;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}


public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}


public long getDuration() {
    return duration;
}


public void setDuration(long duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}


public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}


public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}


public LocalDateTime getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}


public void setEndDate(LocalDateTime endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
```

}`

```
@Entity
```

public class Session {

```
private Long id;
private BigDecimal prize;
private LocalDateTime sessionDate;
private Movie movie;
private MovieCinema movieCinema;

public Session() {
}

public Session(Long id, BigDecimal prize, LocalDateTime sessionDate, Movie movie, MovieCinema movieCinema) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.prize = prize;
    this.sessionDate = sessionDate;
    this.movie = movie;
    this.movieCinema = movieCinema;
}

public Session(BigDecimal prize, LocalDateTime sessionDate, Movie movie, MovieCinema movieCinema) {
    this.prize = prize;
    this.sessionDate = sessionDate;
    this.movie = movie;
    this.movieCinema = movieCinema;
}

public Session(BigDecimal prize, LocalDateTime sessionDate, Movie movie) {

    this.prize = prize;
    this.sessionDate = sessionDate;
    this.movie = movie;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public BigDecimal getPrize() {
    return prize;
}

public void setPrize(BigDecimal prize) {
    this.prize = prize;
}

public LocalDateTime getSessionDate() {
    return sessionDate;
}

public void setSessionDate(LocalDateTime sessionDate) {
    this.sessionDate = sessionDate;
}

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "movieId")
public Movie getMovie() {
    return movie;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    this.movie = movie;
}

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "movieCinemaId")
public MovieCinema getMovieCinema() {
    return movieCinema;
}

public void setMovieCinema(MovieCinema movieCinema) {
    this.movieCinema = movieCinema;
}
```

}

I have 2 table

TableA

Id | name |date | Set

TableB
  Id | date | TableA

I want to select all tableA where TableB.date >= LocalDateTime.now

I thought select * from TableA,TableB where TableB.date >= :now

I want a list of TableA elements with a list of few elements of TableB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGKqH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfGxO.png)

Comment: Can you show us your entity model?

Comment: @jorge.munin and could you please post your entities as code (not as image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved but no using that I did this `public Slice findSessionsByDate(Long movieId, int page, int size) {

```
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
    //Esto devuelve la lista de sesiones validas de una pelicula
    String queryString = "SELECT s  from Session s WHERE s.sessionDate >= :date AND s.movie.id = :movieId";

    queryString += " ORDER BY s.sessionDate";

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).setFirstResult(page * size).setMaxResults(size + 1);

    if (date != null) {
        query.setParameter("date", date);
    }

    if (movieId != null) {
        query.setParameter("movieId", movieId);
    }


    List<Session> sessions = query.getResultList();

    boolean hasNext = sessions.size() == (size + 1);

    if (hasNext) {
        sessions.remove(sessions.size() - 1);
    }

    return new SliceImpl<>(sessions, PageRequest.of(page, size), hasNext);

}`
```

The question I was asking was I wanted to filter by Movies and in the list of movies I wanted to filter sessions of that movies